# How to correctly implement a CollectionEditor?

Tags: c#, collectioneditor

I'm creating a class as shown in the code below. An object of this class is, eventually, shown in a PropertyGrid where, once selected, shows the `...` button that opens the collection editor form.

```cs
[Editor(typeof(MyListBase<>.ItemsEditor), typeof(CollectionEditor))]
internal abstract class MyListBase<T> :  ICustomTypeDescriptor, IList<T> where T : IMyInterface
{
    /*
     * Class implementation
     */

    public class ItemsEditor : CollectionEditor
    {
        public ItemsEditor() : base(typeof(MyListBase<T>)) { }

        protected override object CreateInstance(Type itemType)
        {
            var ctor = itemType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(IMyOtherInterface) });
            if (ctor is not null)
                return ctor.Invoke(new object[] { this.Context.Container });

            return base.CreateInstance(itemType);
        }
    }

}
```

So far, so good.

The problem is that, when pressing the `Add` button the collection editor form displays an error saying that no constructor was found (as the image below).

[image: Collection Form error]

This lead me to believe, later confirmed by breakpoints, that the `CreateInstance` code is not being called.

Further investigation shown that the `ItemsEditor` class is not even being created.

***IF*** I change the line:

```
[Editor(typeof(MyListBase<>.ItemsEditor), typeof(CollectionEditor))]
```

to:

```
[Editor(typeof(MyListBase<>.ItemsEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
```

The `...` button is not shown nor is the collection content in the PropertyGrid.

What am I doing wrong?